# Get data except for data in a column

Tags: php, mysql

So I have the following code:

```
require_once('db.php');

$getUsers = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM users');
$rows = [];

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getUsers)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
    $getSkills = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM skills WHERE id = '" . $r['id'] . "'");
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getSkills)) {
        $rows['skills'] = $r;
    }
}


print(json_encode($rows));
```

Which outputs:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"user1","skills":{"woodcutting":"6","mining":"10"}},{"id":"2","name":user2"}]
```

There are two problems:

- I'd like to get all of the data in the table `skills` EXCEPT for the id, or at-least cut it off before encoding it with json.
- For some reason I can't get the "skills" shown after the first user. user2 should also have a skills object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the columns except the `id` from table `skills`, you can either list all the columns that you want to select, like this:

```
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT column1, column2, another_column FROM `skills` WHERE id = '" . $r['id'] . "'");
```

Or, you can `SELECT` everything and use `unset()` to weed out the `id` column before json-encoding:

```
$getSkills = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM skills WHERE id = '" . $r['id'] . "'");
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getSkills))
{
    unset($r['id']);

    // whatever it is that you want to do.
}
```

The `skills` are not shown except for the last user (?) because you are re-assigning it in every iteration of the `while` loop. Here is something you can do instead:

```
require_once('db.php');

$getUsers = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM users');
$rows = array();

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getUsers))
{
    $skills = array();
    $tempRow = $r;
    $getSkills = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM skills WHERE id = '" . $r['id'] . "'");
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getSkills))
    {
        unset($r['id']);  // since you don't want the `id`.
        $skills[] = $r;
    }
    $tempRow['skills'] = $skills;
    $rows[] = $tempRow;
}


print(json_encode($rows));
```

Hope that helps `:)`

Comment: Thanks, but isn't what I expected. ResultS:

{"skills":[{"woodcutting":"22","mining":"33"},{"woodcutting":"6","mining":"10"}],"0":{"id":"1","name":"user1"},"1":{"id":"2","name":"user2"}}

Comment: It was a mistake on my part. Updated the answer :)

Comment: Almost, but the skills array should have a label "skills" before the object {} So { name: user, skills: {} }

Comment: @devs Try `$tempRow['skills'] = $skills` instead of `array_push($tempRow, $skills)`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need something similar to this:

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getSkills)) {
    unset($r['id']);
    $rows['skills'] = $r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Point-1:** Unset `id` like `unset($r['id'])` to remove from `array() $r`. Before unsset `id` keep id to a variable because you used it for next query.
- **Point-2:** May be there is no data exist in `skills` those IDs. As a result you did not get `skills`. Suggest you to query by those IDs whether any data exist or not in `skills` table.

  ```
  while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getUsers)) {
      $id = $r['id'];
      unset($r['id']);
      $rows[] = $r;
      $getSkills = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM skills WHERE id = '$id'");
      while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getSkills)) {
          $rows['skills'] = $r;
      }
   }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, for problem #2 I'm sure there is data in the skills table for id 2, because I'm working on it locally and I can see it.

Comment: So add an error reporting to see if error occurred. `$getSkills = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM skills WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysqli_error($db));`. Another suggestion: can try using `mysqli_fetch_array()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: 1. No errors reported.
2. Just added a bunch of numbers to to the results, it didn't show the other skills.

Comment: Doing this  $rows[]['skills'] = $r; gets both results but isn't formatted correctly.